# How can I run this command (clang++ *.cpp -o main && ./main) in :term on Vim?

Tags: terminal

In Neovim, my code compiles and runs fine with this command:
`:term clang++ main.cpp -o main && ./main`
, but not in Vim.

When I run it in Vim the code neither compiles nor executes. I get the following error:

```
clang-10: error: no such file or directory: '&&'
```

but when I do `:term`, and inside it run `clang++ main.cpp -o main && ./main`, it works.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you [edit] to be more specific with what you’re typing before you get the error?

Comment: Thank you @D.BenKnoble!! Edited.

Comment: `&&` is a shell construct, so you need to run a shell that runs your clang command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t believe (though I can’t find reference to prove it) that `:terminal` in vim wraps the passed command in a shell. So to use shell features you need, e.g.,

```
terminal sh -c "clang++ main.cpp -o main && ./main"
```

By itself, however, `:terminal` starts `'shell'`, which is usually `$SHELL`.

Comment: Not work. =/ ```main.cpp: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
  main.cpp: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file```

Comment: It works. Thank you!! Can you edit your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I download the source code of vim from the vim repository on github:

```
https://github.com/vim/vim
```

compile and install with:

```
make && make install
```

and the previous command works:

```
:term clang++ main.cpp -o main && ./main
```

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Better?

Comment: Sure. I guess some recent version used the shell, and yours didn't? FWIW, mine doesn't (8.2.1800)

Comment: apparently this is it. I recompiled vim because the `vim --version` command showed `-clipboard` and I like to copy to the clipboard with `yy`. And consequently fixed the original problem.

Comment: I have `+clipboard`, but who knows

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add the [code_runner](https://github.com/CRAG666/code_runner.nvim) plugin to the confugration of Vim and you can run code for c++ c and c# and python.

Comment: Welcome to Vi and Vim SE and thank you for writing an answer. The question seems to be about *compiling* code while your answer is about *running* code. Maybe you could edit and clarify how your answer addresses the question?